# How to prevent datagrid refresh when binding data using IsAsync in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I'm having a task that put the android logcat logs to datagrid of WPF.
The problem occurs when starting the app, a huge of logs (~80,000 lines of log) must be loaded to the datagrid.
So, I have 2 solution for this problem:

- Firstly, If  I use an ObservableCollection as ItemSource, datagrid will update line by line. It takes a minutes to load ~10,000 lines => Toooooo slow...
  [Do not use IsAsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO0dA.gif)
- Then, I use a List as ItemSource and set IsAsync to true. I bind the data programmatically every one line added (or every 100,1000 lines added). It takes only 20s to load ~90.000 lines. But the datagrid is refreshing (relaunch?) every notifyChange called, so I can not do anything in the datagrid.
  [Use IsAsync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egTSX.gif)

If you have any solution to solve this problem or just a solution to prevent datagrid refreshing, please help me. Thank you very much~

### View:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding LogItemVMs,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=OneWay,IsAsync=True}"
      EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization ="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing ="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
      VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel"
      GridLinesVisibility="None">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Line" Width="auto">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Line,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

### ViewModel

```
public List<LogItemVM> LogItemVMs { get; set; }
private void executeCmd()
{
new Thread(() =>
{
    Process cmd = _commandImpl.CreateProcess("adb logcat -v threadtime");

    try
    {
        cmd.Start();
        string line;
        LogCount = 0;
        while ((line = cmd.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            LogInfo lif = _logInfoManager.ParseLogInfos(line);
            if (lif != null)
            {
                LogItemVM livm = new LogItemVM(lif);
                System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                    DispatcherPriority.Background,
                    new Action(() =>
                    {
                        LogItemVMs.Add(livm);
                        LogCount++;
                        //if ((int)livm.Line % 1000 == 0)
                        onChanged(this, "LogItemVMs");
                        onChanged(this, "LogCount");
                    }));
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        if (!cmd.HasExited)
            cmd.Kill();
    }
}).Start();
}
```

Comment: As a note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and `Mode=OneWay` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. The Binding is OneWay by default, and UpdateSourceTrigger only has an effect on TwoWay or OnwWayToSource Bindings. Besides that, have you considered to populate the source collection before assigning it to the LogItemVMs property? The property would have to fire the PropertyChanged event only once.

Comment: @Clemens: thanks for your response. The process still returns the logs until I close that, so I must call PropertyChanged for every change or after specified time => The datagrid is always relaunched when updating.

Comment: You would then only add elements to an ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Clemens: Please refer my attached images of each solution. Thank you~

Comment: @Clemens: This is a dynamic source, that I get the data real time and show to datagrid